# Capistrano 3.1: rake assets precompile not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I am new to Capistrano and trying to precompile the assets. after entering command `cap production deploy` my code is successfully deployed on the server,but my assets are not compiled.below is my deploy.rb file.

```
       #SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake] = "bundle exec rake"
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.1.0'

set :application, 'woi'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:sanjay-salunkhe/cap.git'
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :stages, ["production"]

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app
 set :deploy_to, '/home/webuser/apps/cap/'

# Default value for :scm is :git
# set :scm, :git

# Default value for :format is :pretty
# set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
# set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
 set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
       execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end


  desc 'precompiling assets..............'
  task :composer_install do
    on roles(:web) do
      within release_path do
        execute :rake, "assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production"
      end
    end
  end

  after :publishing, 'deploy:composer_install'



end
```

Below are my logs

```
   DEBUG [cf204b99]     /usr/bin/env: 
DEBUG [cf204b99]    rake
DEBUG [cf204b99]    : No such file or directory
DEBUG [cf204b99]    
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:94:in `exit_status='
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:142:in `block (4 levels) in _exe
```

also if possible then please send me the good documentation link for Capistrano 3.1.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide the log. Does it show `rake assets:precompile` in logs while deploying?

Comment: no it doesnt show rake assets:precompile anywhere in revision.log file.i have added revision.log file content in my question.

Comment: no I am talking about the log printed on console while deploying.

Comment: no it is not showing me rake assets:precompile anywhere in log.check the log updated in the question.

Comment: @UandI - I have updated my deploye.rb file and now i am getting error as DEBUG [cf204b99]  /usr/bin/env: 
DEBUG [cf204b99]  rake
DEBUG [cf204b99]  : No such file or directory
DEBUG [cf204b99]  
cap aborted! . please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i manged to deploy my app using capastrano 3.Actually i had not included below two lines in my capfile.

```
 require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rails'
```

After including these two lines my issue has been resolved.

Comment: Also remember to add these to your gemfile. gem 'capistrano-rvm' and gem 'capistrano-rails'

Answer (score 1):

You need to change directory and compile assets in one command.
I'm using this:
`execute "cd #{release_path}/ && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile"`

Sometimes (it depends on server configuration) capistrano can raise an error that it can't find 'bundle', then You have to find where bundle is located on the server by using:
`which bundle`
And add the full path to above line, in my configuration it was required to provide full path:
`execute "cd #{release_path}/ && RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/bin/bundle exec rake assets:precompile"`

Answer (score 0):

I had to update node and install yarn on my server to get rake assets:precompile to work.
The frustrating part is that it was not producing any error or feedback. I only discovered this was the problem when I did rake assets:clobber

Answer (score -2):

For Rails 4 and Capistrano 3, I find it unnecessary to write a Capistrano recipe to precompile assets for production.

Instead before I

`cap production deploy`

I just run

`rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

from my local machine and then go on and deploy.

Comment: how does it helps? does it sync with production server?

Comment: NOT a good solution. In this case the assets are being uploaded precompiled to repository and this will increase a lot the time spent in each deploy, because now the repo is extremely large sized